# Is there official guide for Python 3.x release lifecycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I just noticed Python 3.2 was removed from the drop down selector in [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/). I have a framework using Python 3.3, so I'd like to know when it'll share the same fate, and move to a newer version before this happens.

Is there an official guide on how long Python `3.x` gets support, backports, etc.? I couldn't find any information about Python release lifecycle on Python's home page or via search engines.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Updated schedule (as of August 2022):

- Python 3.4: reached End Of Life
- Python 3.5: reached End Of Life
- Python 3.6: reached End Of Life
- Python 3.7: security fixes only, no
  bug fixes will be provided; End Of Life: **2023-06-27**
- Python 3.8: security fixes only, no
  bug fixes will be provided; End Of Life: **2024-10**
- Python 3.9: security fixes only, no
  bug fixes will be provided; End Of Life: **2025-10**
- Python 3.10: security fixes **AND** bug fixes will be provided; End Of Life: **2026-10**
- Python 3.11: security fixes **AND** bug fixes will be provided; End Of Life: **2027-10**

Source: https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches

Also notice that Python release cycle has changed to 12 months since Python 3.9. See [PEP-602 for more details](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0602/). It used to be 18 months for Python 3.8 and prior releases. This means we should see Python 3.9 before end of year 2020!

Answer (score 52):

Yes, you could look at the [table in the Pythons Developer Guide](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) for most releases. Specifically `Python 3.3` will have security fixes until  2017-09-29.

Additionally, appropriate `PEP`s exist (google-able or from the devguide table) for each branch where a lifespan section specifies these. For `3.3` in [`PEP 398`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#lifespan):

> `3.3` will receive bugfix updates approximately every 4-6 months for approximately 18 months. After the release of `3.4.0` final, a final `3.3` bugfix update will be released. After that, security updates (source only) will be released until 5 years after the release of `3.3` final, which will be September 2017.

---

For the rest of the actively maintained Pythons, the PEPs are:

- Python 3.9 [PEP 596](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596)
- Python 3.8 [PEP 569](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569)
- Python 3.7 [PEP 537](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0537)
- Python 3.6 [PEP 494](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494)
- Python 3.5 [PEP 478](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478)

See the *Lifespan* and *Schedule* sections for details on these.

Comment: For the release and end-of-life dates of former Python versions, see [this link](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches).

Answer (score 9):

Each Python release gets a Release Schedule PEP which includes information about the planned lifespan. For 3.3: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#id11